# Multiple selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I know I can have multiple selections like this:

```
 $("input,submit,textarea")
```

Is there a way to bind these 3 together

```
$('input[name="input"]')
$('input[name="submit"]')
$('input[name="textarea"]')
```

or do I have to write it like

```
 $('input[name="input"],input[name="submit"],input[name="textarea"]')
```

?

I'm looking for something like  `$('input[name="input"&"submit"&"textarea"]`(this is not valid, of course), to not write 'input' 3 times.

Comment: $('input[name="test1"],input[name="test2"],input[name="test3"]') is ok. But you could just have tested it in less time that it would have taken you to write this question :)

Comment: No, what I mean is if I can write something like one single 'input=' that includes all three tests.

Comment: Have look at available attribute selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/ (or selectors in general: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Comment: If you're looking for an absolute, then separate by commas. If not, you can use a "contains" selector, but that leaves you open for other element confliction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "simple way" to achieve what you want. Writing them one by one is probably the best solution if you don't want to alter the DOM and save performance, but if you have a lot of element, it can be a real pain to write them all.

The best solution really is to group them with a common class and you it to select all related element.

In case you don't want that, you could use the `filter` method, but then, it will be slower cause it loop on all inputs.

```
$('input[name]').filter(function(){
    return $.inArray(this.name, ['test1','test2', '...']) > -1;
});
```

All you have to do is to write the different input name in the array.